# How to position the label of a horizontal matplotlib colorbar object exactly at the center of the colorbar below or above?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, axis-labels, colorbar

Here is the code I have borrowed from [matplotlib sample examples](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.colorbar.html) with slight modifications to produce a horizontal colorbar for an image with a properly placed label:

```
from matplotlib import colors
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(19680801)
cmap = "cool"

fig, axs = plt.subplots()

# Generate data with a range that varies from one plot to the next.
data = (1 / 10) * np.random.rand(10, 20) * 1e-6
image = axs.imshow(data, cmap=cmap)
axs.label_outer()

# Find the min and max of all colors for use in setting the color scale.
vmin = image.get_array().min()
vmax = image.get_array().max()
norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=vmin, vmax=vmax)

cbar = fig.colorbar(image, ax=axs, orientation='horizontal', fraction=.1)
cbar.ax.set_ylabel('$[M_\u2609 kpc^{{-2}}]$', position=(30,1), fontsize=20, rotation=0)


plt.show()
```

But here is the output which I don't want.

[image: Figure1]

I want a label that is exactly sitting at the center of the `colorbar` (below or above). After changing the coordinates given to `position` in the code above, it does not seem that there is any flexibility in determining the position of the label. Is there something I am not aware of in the context of `matplotlib` colorbars? Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Please submit a minimal reproducible example: a small piece of code that reproduces your problem but completely self-contained. Consider also the guidelines [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

An axis label (`ylabel`) is designed to be placed along the corresponding axis. A *title*, on the other hand, is, by design, positioned centered over the axes object. So instead of using an `set_ylabel`, you should be using `set_title`.

```
cbar.ax.set_title('$[M_\u2609 kpc^{{-2}}]$', fontsize=20)
```

[image]

For more information about the different parts of a figure, see [this example "Anatomy of a Figure"](https://matplotlib.org/gallery/showcase/anatomy.html#sphx-glr-gallery-showcase-anatomy-py)

[image]